# ODBC - insert on a linked table failed

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

I have the Front_end in the MS-Access and the database is on theserver. Have connected the database with the ODBC connecter.

I have attached the sub-form under the form. and assign the `TAb`. while adding the new Record, when I clicked on the form it is showing me this error `ODBC - insert on a linked table failed. (Error 3155)`. The error just pops out while clicking every on the table. even when I click on the close button, before closing the window this popup comes `ODBC - insert on a linked table failed. (Error 3155)`. Dont know how to rid off from this trouble shoot.

Important Note:

1. The Main form has the table linked  - `tblInvoices` ( This table is the parent table of
   the `tblInvoiceDetails`.
2. SubForm under the main form has the Linked table - `tblInvoiceDetails` - this table is
   linked with the parent table `tblInvoices`.
3. When i m entering the some data on main Form, and then press enter to go under Subform
   then this popup appears `ODBC - insert on a linked table "tblInvoices" failed`.
4. `tblInvoices` has a large amount of data ~1m rows.
5. `tblInvoiceDetails` has a large amount of data ~2M rows.
6. In `tblInvoiceDetails` there is the foriegn key which is refer to the `tblInvoices`
   Unique key.

Have Tried:

1. Have recreated the database with the new `tblInvoices` and
   `tblInvoiceDetails` with limited rows.
2. In `tblInvoices` and `tblInvoiceDetails` we have added and checked the primary key in each table.

Screen Shots:

[image]

If anything you professionals required then please let me know. will share you.

Thank you. for your help.

Comment: Is there any other part of the error message telling you the underlying mysql error? Alternatively, try to log the error on mysql side. Until then, we can only guess the reason for the error.

Comment: There is not any other part of the error message. when I click on the White part ( as shown in the picture) then immediately the msg box comes in front. How could i get the error log from the mysql?

Answer (score 0):

The error is not with respect to Ms-access its the limitation to ODBC connector.

sql - Issue with ODBC Object connection - Open limitation to 65k rows - Stack Overflow.

Please read : [Issue with ODBC Object connection - Open limitation to 65k rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975047/issue-with-odbc-object-connection-open-limitation-to-65k-rows#:%7E:text=sql%20%2D%20Issue%20with%20ODBC%20Object,to%2065k%20rows%20%2D%20Stack%20Overflow)

This works for me:

- Older Excel versions (prior to 2007) indeed have a limit of some 65k+
  rows per worksheet. Run your code and reference any object Lib
  starting w/Excel 2007 and up (max 1,048,576 rows per worksheet, Lib
  version correspondingly 12.x and up).
- Have Change the Provider = `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` with `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0`. Update the lib with the higher version & Latest version.

Thanks.